# what's the difference between removing an array element with undefined and delete?

Tags: javascript

MDN defines the difference below but I'm not understanding the difference. I
created an array and then deleted an element, then tried calling the element and it returned undefined.

```
var ary=[0,1,2,3,4];
delete ary[3];
ary[3]// returns undefined
ary.length //returns 5

var ary2=[0,1,2,3,4];
ary2[2]=undefined
ary2[2]// returns undefined
ary2.length// returns 5
```

When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

When the delete operator removes an array element, that element is no longer in the array. In the following example, trees[3] is removed with delete.

```
var trees = ["redwood","bay","cedar","oak","maple"];
delete trees[3];
if (3 in trees) {
// this does not get executed
}
```

If you want an array element to exist but have an undefined value, use the undefined value instead of the delete operator. In the following example, trees[3] is assigned the value undefined, but the array element still exists:

```
var trees = ["redwood","bay","cedar","oak","maple"];
trees[3] = undefined;
if (3 in trees) {
// this gets executed
}
```

Comment: Array length... That's the main thing. And yeah, the index.

Comment: Neither of those methods really "remove" an element. Are you asking how to really remove an element?

Comment: I'm curious as to what the difference between them is. MDN is describing a difference but to me they seem to effect an array the same way, so I think I'm missing something. it looks like they both remove an array element but leave the array with just an empty slot but with the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since array is nothing but object.. delete removes the '3' key from the object without changing anything else. However setting 3rd element to undefined doesn't remove the key 3 but sets its value to undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a[1] = undefined;
console.log('1' in a); // true
delete a[1];
console.log('1' in a); // false
console.log(a.length); // 3
console.log(a); // [1, undefined, 3]
```

If you want to remove in the middle of an array you should use splice:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.splice(1, 1);
console.log(a.length); // 2
console.log(a); // [1, 3]
```

The arguments for splice is:

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

[See more over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)